# Tomcat 8.5 and java 11. Cannot acquire data source. Name is not bound in this Context

Tags: tomcat, eclipselink, persistence, java-11, tomcat8.5

I've already read lots of topics about this but I can't solve my problem after deploying project in tomcat 8.5.57 and java 11. Before it was under Tomcat 7 and java 7.

Error is:

```
javax.persistence.PersistenceException: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [java:comp/env/jdbc/scheduled].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception resolving reference [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:766)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.getAbstractSession(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryDelegate.java:304)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManagerImpl(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:336)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryImpl.createEntityManager(EntityManagerFactoryImpl.java:302)
    at org.quartz.core.JobRunShell.run(JobRunShell.java:202)
    at org.quartz.simpl.SimpleThreadPool$WorkerThread.run(SimpleThreadPool.java:573)
Caused by: Exception [EclipseLink-7060] (Eclipse Persistence Services - 2.5.2.v20140319-9ad6abd): org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException
Exception Description: Cannot acquire data source [java:comp/env/jdbc/scheduled].
Internal Exception: javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception resolving reference [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.]
    at org.eclipse.persistence.exceptions.ValidationException.cannotAcquireDataSource(ValidationException.java:520)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:109)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.DatasourceLogin.connectToDatasource(DatasourceLogin.java:162)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.setOrDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:204)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.sessions.DatabaseSessionImpl.loginAndDetectDatasource(DatabaseSessionImpl.java:741)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerFactoryProvider.login(EntityManagerFactoryProvider.java:239)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.internal.jpa.EntityManagerSetupImpl.deploy(EntityManagerSetupImpl.java:685)
    ... 10 more
Caused by: javax.naming.NamingException: Unexpected exception resolving reference [Root exception is java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.]
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:856)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:827)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:827)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:827)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:159)
    at org.apache.naming.SelectorContext.lookup(SelectorContext.java:140)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.InitialContext.lookup(InitialContext.java:413)
    at org.eclipse.persistence.sessions.JNDIConnector.connect(JNDIConnector.java:103)
    ... 15 more
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Timer already cancelled.
    at java.base/java.util.Timer.sched(Timer.java:398)
    at java.base/java.util.Timer.schedule(Timer.java:249)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.registerCleaner(ConnectionPool.java:1407)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.access$400(ConnectionPool.java:56)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool$PoolCleaner.start(ConnectionPool.java:1481)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.initializePoolCleaner(ConnectionPool.java:533)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.init(ConnectionPool.java:453)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.ConnectionPool.<init>(ConnectionPool.java:154)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.pCreatePool(DataSourceProxy.java:118)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceProxy.createPool(DataSourceProxy.java:107)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.createDataSource(DataSourceFactory.java:560)
    at org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory.getObjectInstance(DataSourceFactory.java:244)
    at org.apache.naming.factory.FactoryBase.getObjectInstance(FactoryBase.java:96)
    at java.naming/javax.naming.spi.NamingManager.getObjectInstance(NamingManager.java:330)
    at org.apache.naming.NamingContext.lookup(NamingContext.java:839)
    ... 25 more
```

Error says there is a problem acquiring datasource because it seems to not find "scheduled".
I think there is something to change in tomcat 8.5 and java 11 (even if i have referenced 1.7 in my pom.xml. I also tried to change to java 11 without luck)

This is my persistence.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<persistence version="2.1" xmlns="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence http://xmlns.jcp.org/xml/ns/persistence/persistence_2_1.xsd">
  <persistence-unit name="ScheduledPU" transaction-type="RESOURCE_LOCAL">
    <provider>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.PersistenceProvider</provider>
    <class>...</class>
    <shared-cache-mode>NONE</shared-cache-mode>
    
    <properties>
      
      <property name="eclipselink.jdbc.uppercase-columns" value="true"/>
      <non-jta-data-source>java:comp/env/jdbc/scheduled</non-jta-data-source>
      
    </properties>
  </persistence-unit>
</persistence>
```

This is my context.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Context antiJARLocking="true" path="/scheduled">
    
    <Resource name="jdbc/scheduled"
        auth="Container"
        type="javax.sql.DataSource"
        factory="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.DataSourceFactory"
        testWhileIdle="true"
        testOnBorrow="true"
        testOnReturn="false"
        validationQuery="SELECT 1"
        validationInterval="30000"
        timeBetweenEvictionRunsMillis="30000"
        maxActive="5"
        minIdle="1"
        maxWait="300000"
        initialSize="1"
        minEvictableIdleTimeMillis="30000"
        jmxEnabled="true"
        jdbcInterceptors="org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.ConnectionState;org.apache.tomcat.jdbc.pool.interceptor.StatementFinalizer"
        username="xxx"
        password="yyy"
        driverClassName="com.mysql.jdbc.Driver"
        url="jdbc:mysql://..."/>
        
</Context>
```

This is my web.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<web-app version="2.5" xmlns="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee http://java.sun.com/xml/ns/javaee/web-app_2_5.xsd">
    
    <servlet>
        <servlet-name>QuartzInitializer</servlet-name>
        <servlet-class>org.quartz.ee.servlet.QuartzInitializerServlet</servlet-class>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>shutdown-on-unload</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <init-param>
            <param-name>start-scheduler-on-load</param-name>
            <param-value>true</param-value>
        </init-param>
        <load-on-startup>1</load-on-startup>
    </servlet>
    
    <session-config>
        <session-timeout>
            30
        </session-timeout>
    </session-config>
</web-app>
```

This is my pom.xml:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <properties>
        <endorsed.dir>${project.build.directory}/endorsed</endorsed.dir>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
    </properties>
    
    <dependencies>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.transaction</groupId>
            <artifactId>jta</artifactId>
            <version>1.1</version>
        </dependency>

        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.quartz-scheduler</groupId>
            <artifactId>quartz-jobs</artifactId>
            <version>2.2.1</version>
        </dependency>
    
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
            <artifactId>slf4j-log4j12</artifactId>
            <version>1.7.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>eclipselink</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.eclipse.persistence</groupId>
            <artifactId>org.eclipse.persistence.jpa.modelgen.processor</artifactId>
            <version>2.5.2</version>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        
        <dependency>
            <groupId>c3p0</groupId>
            <artifactId>c3p0</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1.2</version>
        </dependency>

        <dependency>
            <groupId>com.mchange</groupId>
            <artifactId>mchange-commons-java</artifactId>
            <version>0.2.10</version>
        </dependency>
        
    </dependencies>
    
    <build>
        <finalName>scheduled</finalName>
        <defaultGoal>package</defaultGoal>
        <plugins>
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>3.1</version>
                <configuration>
                    <source>1.7</source>
                    <target>1.7</target>
                    <compilerArguments>
                        <endorseddirs>${endorsed.dir}</endorseddirs>
                    </compilerArguments>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
            
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-dependency-plugin</artifactId>
                <version>2.6</version>
                <executions>
                    <execution>
                        <phase>validate</phase>
                        <goals>
                            <goal>copy</goal>
                        </goals>
                        <configuration>
                            <outputDirectory>${endorsed.dir}</outputDirectory>
                            <silent>true</silent>
                            <artifactItems>
                                <artifactItem>
                                    <groupId>javax</groupId>
                                    <artifactId>javaee-endorsed-api</artifactId>
                                    <version>7.0</version>
                                    <type>jar</type>
                                </artifactItem>
                            </artifactItems>
                        </configuration>
                    </execution>
                </executions>
            </plugin>
            
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

Thanks for your help

***EDIT:***
I get error on:
return (DataSource) env.lookup(lkp);
lkp is a string containing correct value ("jdbc/xxx")

Any ideas?

Answer (score 1):

I solved placing mysql connector jar inside tomcat\lib